# How can I center an item on the screen programmatically?

Tags: android

How can I center an item on the screen programmatically?

I want to set imageView in the center of any screen that will run my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your parent is `RelativeLayout` use this:

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW_ID);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)myImageView.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
myImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```